# Common directory to play video and courses accessible to all Production and Staging Slots

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an LMS that I developed over a decade ago that has been serving up a six hour video course.  The course exists in a folder called "Courses" in my .Net Framework application.

I am finally in the process of upgrading this app - moving to .Net Core and want to be able to have a common directory - not directly in my Application - that can be accessed from versions of my application in the both the Staging and Production slots without having to upload several Gb of media with the program for both slots.  Any suggestions - best practices for handling video/lms files like that?

Comment: Using Blob storage, you decouple the media from your app. Your app can also create shared access signatures to protect your videos.

Comment: Belated thanks for your response - will do that - Trying to put a check mark beside your response - but it seems to be unavailable.